# Simplify expressions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
[(3√11)^2×0.5×79]^−1 , rounded to 2 decimal places
```

I need to simplify this expression and display a result of 3.14. I can do it on paper, but I'm not sure to achieve it on Python. I've tried the following:

```
print (((((3/11**(1/2)))**2*0.5*7)/9)**(−1))
```

which gives me an error when i get to negative 1, so I don't know if I'm close or far off.

Also can I round off the answer on the same line as the line with the expression? e.g.:

```
    print round((((((3/11**(1/2)))**2*0.5*7)/9)**(−1)),2)
```

or do I need to store it in a variable first and only then round it off. Essentially I'm trying to put it on one line, but if it isn't possible I totally understand

Comment: If you're trying to simplify a math equation then you need [math.se], or are you trying to format a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

print(round(1/(((3/11**(1/2))**2*0.5*7)/9),2))

Comment: It does yes, Thank you. Can you walk me through it if possible? I think I see what I did wrong, but I'm still not certain why mine didn't work

Comment: check blhsing answers, this is the explanation

Answer (score 1):

The `−` in the `−1` in your expression is actually a [unicode minus sign character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm), not an ASCII character. Replace `−` with the regular ASCII minus sign `-`, and your code would work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to get the pi number, you can use `math.pi`:

```
from math import pi
print(pi)
```

Output:

```
3.141592653589793
```

---

```
from math import pi
print(round(pi,2))
```

Output:

```
3.14
```

But you want a own code for it, i understand so you are using the non-real minus sign so need `-`, instead of  `−`, the width non-real one is longer:

```
print(round((((((3/11**(1/2)))**2*0.5*7)/9)**(-1)),2))
```

Output:

```
3.14
```